# Getting nginx's welcome page instead of rails home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, dockerfile, nginx-config

Hi i have created rails application(rails new railsapp). My docker file is

```
# Dockerfile

FROM ruby:2.7.0-alpine as builder

# Install dependencies for native extensions

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base libffi-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache sqlite-libs
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata sqlite-dev
# This will be our application rootfolder

WORKDIR /application

# Copy all the content from current directory

COPY . /application

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./

# Build our application

RUN bundle install
RUN bundle exec rake

# Here we start a new stage
FROM nginx:latest
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /application/public /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I have built image by runnning docker image build -t railsapp .
When i run ,

```
 docker container run -p 8888:80 railsapp
```

I get "welcome nginx page". I should get rails page.. But not displaying. I don't know what mistake I have made in docker file. I'm newbie to the docker. please someone help me. Thanks in advance.

nginx.conf

```
 server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;


location / {
```

// i don't know what to specify in the following directives. I have written the following code for react application.

```
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri /index.html;                 
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete default nginx html file, or create your own nginx config file and specify path to your files

```
root /var/www/UI;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html$is_args$args;
```

Comment: I have created nginx.html file. But I don't know what to specify in root directive. Can u please help me?

Comment: @user3359964 try to move your all files to another folder, like /var/www/UI, then use this section in nginx conf file in you docker container ( see in my comment bellow)

Comment: Ok.. I will try that. Don't I need to add CMD ["bin/rails","server"] in Docker file???

Comment: Ooh, you need, because it will start your app when you will run container, but dont forget to add WORKSPACE and specify path to your rail app.